# jQuery UI - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a problem using jQuery ui and `dialog()` function:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'dialog'

I've googled around many people with the same problem solved that issue with a correct inclusion of jQuery library.

This is the header: http://pastebin.com/e1cTKGK9

And this is the gpf1.js source: http://pastebin.com/0jXhU503

Comment: In the future, please post some code in the question itself (don't rely on external sites). Also: try to narrow down the problem to a specific piece of code, so you don't have to post a "wall of code". Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 48 in your gpf1.js file

```
$.dialog();
```

This `$.` sign applies the dialog method to the whole jquery element. you should use the dialog method to a DOM element you want like:

```
$(foo).dialog()
```

And here's part of the DEMO from jqueryui.com.

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: solved thanx. anyway now i have another problem (or maybe it's the default behaviour of dialog): the <input> element identified by the selector simply disappear from the markup language, it seems that is entirely removed by the dialog event. is this correct?

Comment: You should set this 'modal' config param to true to use modal form when using dialog() method:$( "foo" ).dialog({modal: true}). For more information please refer to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form :)

Comment: @luke: Try wrapping the `<input>` in a `<div>` and applying `dialog` to that, instead.

Comment: @PPvG: same result, it seems that dialog() 'transforms' the div identified by selector in the alert dialog...

Comment: solved using a markup zone hidded with 'display: none;' for the dialogs. @PPvG: i'll keep in mind ur advice, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed with the snippet bellow

```
// http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921
if(! $.isFunction($.fn.curCSS)) {
   $.curCSS = $.css; 
   $.fn.curCSS = $.fn.css; 
   var mouseY, lastY = 0; 
}
```